# Multipart get from s3 with boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I store big zip files in a s3 bucket so i'd like to download them by chunks using the python boto3 library.

I first tried to use `object.download_fileobj` method but there's no way to get only parts of the object so I now use `s3.get` method which supports a `PartNumber=X` argument.

However i'm unable to find the number of parts before i start to get parts.
I mean if i call get without given a part number in argument i get the following response:

```
s3.Object('mybucket', 'mytest.zip').get()
```

> {'ETag': '"493458a23b7d2ed524e8f144aa9e91f4-27"', 'LastModified':
>   datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 23, 9, 53, 48, tzinfo=tzutc()),
>   'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'RequestId':
>   'E67ABBE9682AE0CA', 'HTTPHeaders': {'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
>   'x-amz-id-2':
>   'Kymvd3rkQZFkjOdnNvbh1f0OG2zFzwJQEai++kvfnZSNtQ2cSQ7wmASMZxT17xg/WJJ29xBxyUQ=',
>   'date': 'Thu, 23 Feb 2017 10:55:02 GMT', 'last-modified': 'Thu, 23 Feb
>   2017 09:53:48 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonS3', 'content-type':
>   'application/zip', 'x-amz-request-id': 'E67ABBE9682AE0CA',
>   'content-length': '222492172', 'etag':
>   '"493458a23b7d2ed524e8f144aa9e91f4-27"'}, 'HostId':
>   'Kymvd3rkQZFkjOdnNvbh1f0OG2zFzwJQEai++kvfnZSNtQ2cSQ7wmASMZxT17xg/WJJ29xBxyUQ=',
>   'HTTPStatusCode': 200}, 'ContentLength': 222492172, 'ContentType':
>   'application/zip', 'Body': , 'AcceptRanges': 'bytes', 'Metadata': {}}

We can see that there's no `PartCount` here

If I do the same but with `PartNumber=1`:

```
 s3.Object('mybucket', 'mytest.zip').get(PartNumber=1)
```

> {'ETag': '"493458a23b7d2ed524e8f144aa9e91f4-27"', 'LastModified':
>   datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 23, 9, 53, 48, tzinfo=tzutc()),
>   'PartsCount': 27, 'ContentRange': 'bytes 0-8388607/222492172',
>   'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'RequestId':
>   '2EE3109196C76834', 'HTTPHeaders': {'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
>   'x-amz-id-2':
>   'Pl4ybedoDA99xCH2fa5zuge9Az7rPxZET+EB2fAZ4BtTDo5dqw/fJZ8PNu3vM5/0mTUkj9/AqhY=',
>   'x-amz-mp-parts-count': '27', 'date': 'Thu, 23 Feb 2017 10:58:20 GMT',
>   'etag': '"493458a23b7d2ed524e8f144aa9e91f4-27"', 'content-range':
>   'bytes 0-8388607/222492172', 'content-type': 'application/zip',
>   'server': 'AmazonS3', 'x-amz-request-id': '2EE3109196C76834',
>   'content-length': '8388608', 'last-modified': 'Thu, 23 Feb 2017
>   09:53:48 GMT'}, 'HostId':
>   'Pl4ybedoDA99xCH2fa5zuge9Az7rPxZET+EB2fAZ4BtTDo5dqw/fJZ8PNu3vM5/0mTUkj9/AqhY=',
>   'HTTPStatusCode': 206}, 'ContentLength': 8388608, 'ContentType':
>   'application/zip', 'Body': , 'AcceptRanges': 'bytes', 'Metadata': {}}

I know can see the number of chunks

> 'PartsCount': 27

Is there a way to get the number of chunks before I start to download the file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`head_object`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object) to get that number. Or, since you're using the object resource, [`Object.parts_count`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.parts_count).

Comment: Actually `Object.parts_count` returns `None` and the head_object only contains the following keys `['ETag', 'LastModified', 'AcceptRanges', 'ResponseMetadata', 'Metadata', 'ContentLength', 'ContentType']`

Comment: If you pass `PartNumber=1` as an argument to `head_object`, it will return `PartsCount`, which contains the number of parts.